# hold node reference in yaml-cpp

Tags: yaml, yaml-cpp

When I'm running following code with yaml-cpp library:

```
YAML::Node node1 = YAML::Load("{ hello: [item1, item2] }");
YAML::Node node2 = node1;

node1 = node1["hello"];

std::cout << node2 << "\n";
std::cout << node1 << "\n";
```

I end up with same node contained in both `node1` and `node2` variables. It prints `[item1, item2]` in both cases. Is it the right behavior or something is messed up? I'm wondering how can I keep reference at original node? 
I use g++ 5.1.0 and boost 1.59.0 if it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nodes in yaml-cpp are reference types, not value types; but this isn't implemented consistently. See [this issue](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp/issues/208) on the project page, which highlights this question.

In your specific case, when you write

```
YAML::Node node2 = node1;
```

it makes these two references that refer to the same value; that is, anything you do to one be reflected in the other.

Then, when you write

```
node1 = node1["hello"];
```

it does two things: first, `node1["hello"]` pulls out the (reference to) the `"hello"` key in `node`, which is `[item1, item2]`. Next, it assigns this to `node1`.

This is where the API is somewhat inconsistently implemented. Since `operator=` is treated with reference semantics, this sets the *value* that `node1` references as being replaced. Since `node2` was an alias for `node1`, it, too, has its value replaced.